# Adding brackets to BETWEEN Query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is a shortened version of model query:

```
User::select('users.*')
    ->when(!empty($this->searchInput['search[term]']), function ($query) {
        return $query->where(
            'biography', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->searchInput['search[term]'] . '%'   
        );
    })
    ->when(!empty($this->searchInput['search[location]']), function ($query) {
        return $query->where(
            'country_id',
            $this->searchInput['search[location]']
        );
    })
    ->when(!empty($this->searchInput['engagement']), function ($query) {
        foreach ($this->searchInput['engagement'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === array_key_first($this->searchInput['engagement'])) {
                $query->whereBetween('engagement_rate', $value);
            } else {
                $query->orWhereBetween('engagement_rate', $value);
            }
        }
    });
```

(In case you are wondering, I am using `$key === array_key_first` to ensure the first `BETWEEN` uses `AND`, and afterwards uses `OR` depending on the user's selections)

This equates to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    `users`.*
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `country_id` = '31'
    AND `engagement_rate` BETWEEN '6' AND '20' OR `engagement_rate` BETWEEN '3.5' AND '6'
```

The `whereBetween` in Eloquent does not include brackets, and as such the country_id selector gets ignored. I need the final SQL statement to be the below (with brackets):

```
SELECT
    `users`.*
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `country_id` = '31'
    AND (`engagement_rate` BETWEEN '6' AND '20' OR `engagement_rate` BETWEEN '3.5' AND '6')
```

**My question:**

How can I change my Eloquent query to reflect the above?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses - Check the section that says "If you need to group an "or" condition within parentheses, you may pass a Closure as the first argument to the orWhere method..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [parameter group](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) to the `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween` clauses:

```
User::select('users.*')
// ...
->when(!empty($this->searchInput['engagement']), function ($query) {

    query->where(function ($q) {
        foreach ($this->searchInput['engagement'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === array_key_first($this->searchInput['engagement'])) {
                $q->whereBetween('engagement_rate', $value);
            } else {
                $q->orWhereBetween('engagement_rate', $value);
            }
        }
    });

});
```